# Redis cluster instance consumes more memory than a standalone instance?

Tags: redis

In our redis cluster,

- A master node (redis 3.2.7 with jemalloc 3.6.0, installed using yum, yellow line) used 2.240G of memory
- A slave node (redis 3.2.7 with jemalloc 3.6.0, installed using yum, cyan line) used 1.735G of memory
- **A slave node (redis 3.2.9 with jemalloc 4.0.3, compiled from source, orange line) used 1.531G of memory**
- **A standalone slave (redis 3.2.9 with jemalloc 4.0.3, compiled from source, green line) used 1.008G of memory**

Using a newer version of memory allocator saves about 12% of memory. That's easy to understand. But what makes a 50% more memory usage in the case of a cluster slave node than that of a standalone instance?

[image]

Comment: Are there by any chance a lot of small keys in the database? Redis cluster uses a table mapping each key in the cluster to its designated slot, which adds an overhead, and the more keys you have, the bigger the overhead. In redis 4.0 the data structure holding these keys has been optimized to reduce memory and increase speed.

Comment: By the time I took the snapshot, we had over 5 million keys with a fixed key length of 33 bytes and an average value length of about 58 bytes. So the key-slot mapping table is likely to be the reason of the problem. Thanks, @Not_a_Golfer

Comment: I'll make it an answer for future generations.

Comment: @thirstycrow Would you please tell me what application are you using to track memory? It would help me as I need one.

Comment: @GopsAB We use redis_exporter and prometheus to collect metrics from redis instances, and grafana for visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis cluster uses an internal table, mapping each key in the cluster to its designated slot, which adds an overhead.

And the more keys you have, the bigger the overhead. So especially if you have many many small keys, this is very noticeable, and even slows down saving and loading data to/from RDB.

In redis 4.0 the data structure holding these keys has been optimized to reduce memory and increase speed. For reference - https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3800